# emulator working on eclipse not loading

Tags: android-emulator

I am trying to run hello world program on android emulator using eclipse. emulator starts but my application never loads on emulator.I am using windows 7 starter 32 bit, 1GB RAM , intel Atom 1.66 Ghz processor.can any one help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Usually android emulator runs slow with eclipse. In your cause try [testdoid](http://testdroid.com/). Also, you can view some performance from emulator from eclipse plugin in [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)